# Java SecurityException Cannot locate policy or framework files after updating to latest version

Tags: ibm-jdk, javapolicy

Here's how I launch java

```
java -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=myhostname \
    -Djava.security.policy=/myprogram/java.policy \
    -Dcom.ibm.tools.attach.enable=no -jar \
    /myprogram/myjar.jar
```

and the contents of `java.policy` is

```
grant codeBase "file:/myprogram/myjar.jar" {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

I installed a new version of IBM Java

```
# rpm -qi java-1_8_0-ibm
Version     : 1.8.0_sr5.10
Release     : 30.24.1
Source RPM  : java-1_8_0-ibm-1.8.0_sr5.10-30.24.1.nosrc.rpm
Build Date  : Sun 18 Mar 2018 02:44:37 PM MDT
```

And now I'm getting this error message

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Cannot locate policy or framework files!
    at javax.crypto.b.c(Unknown Source)
    ...
```

The previous version I was using was not showing the same failure

```
# rpm -qi java-1_8_0-ibm
Version     : 1.8.0_sr5.10
Release     : 30.16.1
Source RPM  : java-1_8_0-ibm-1.8.0_sr5.10-30.16.1.nosrc.rpm
Build Date  : Tue 27 Feb 2018 10:22:44 AM MST
```

The release notes say

- Fri Mar 16 2018 pmonrealgonzalez *at* suse *dot* com

  - Fixed priorities of alternatives [bsc#1085018]
- Wed Mar 14 2018 pmonrealgonzalez *at* suse *dot* com

  - Fixed symlinks to policy files on update [bsc#1085018]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RPM file list contains both limited and unlimited policy files

```
# rpm -ql java-1_8_0-ibm
/usr/lib64/jvm-private/java-1.8.0-ibm/jce/vanilla/limited/US_export_policy.jar
/usr/lib64/jvm-private/java-1.8.0-ibm/jce/vanilla/limited/local_policy.jar
/usr/lib64/jvm-private/java-1.8.0-ibm/jce/vanilla/unlimited/US_export_policy.jar
/usr/lib64/jvm-private/java-1.8.0-ibm/jce/vanilla/unlimited/local_policy.jar
```

> For Java 8.0.5.10, Java 7.1.4.20, Java 7.0.10.20, Java 6.1.8.60, and onward, the restricted policy files are the default.

This explains why the limited policy files are now symlinked.

The fix for me was to specify the unlimited policy files using:

```
-Dcom.ibm.security.jurisdictionPolicyDir=/usr/lib64/jvm-private/java-1.8.0-ibm/jce/vanilla/unlimited
```